# Synonym for "pet" (or "dog" in particular) that expresses the deep affection of the owner towards it

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that expresses the strong emotional bound many pet owners have towards their furry fellows, especially dogs.

Most synonyms for "dog" I have found so far seem to be rather neutral or even negative. However I suppose that there is a term (most likely very colloquial but frequently used in the "circle of dog owners") that expresses the emotional quality of the relation between pet and owner much better. Coming from the point that for many owners a dog is somehow comparable to a child there are surely stronger connoted terms than just "pet","fellow","puppy" etc.

Comment: 'Pooch' and 'bow wow' are rarely used when one considers a dog vicious.

Comment: [**furry friend**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/furry-friend) (British English, humorous) ***a pet, esp a cat or a dog***

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I wouldn't mind knowing what makes that "dog vicious" predilected as regards the plentiful population of the vicious dog  unless it's at a disadvantage… a black sheep then…

Comment: *doggo, pupper, boy/girl, ...

Answer (score 0):

Use a term that draws a parallel between pets and children such as  (bold added):

> Want to make a Dog Trainer’s hair stand on end? Refer to your dog as a “**Furbaby**” and watch the fur fly! Our *compawsionate* Holiday Barn Trainers totally understand the term “furbaby” as they too have **4-legged children** whom they adore. — [Holiday Barn Pet Resorts](https://holidaybarn.com/blog/furbabies/)

Both of these can be used for dogs and cats and similar pets.